# Find all 4 digits numbers that $ABCD=(CD)^2$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

Please help me to solve following problem:

Find all 4 digits numbers such that $ABCD=(CD)^2$.(any of $A,B,C,D$ is a digit!)

I know one of solutions is $5776=(76)^2$.

Comment: Also $0625=625=25^2$, if we allow $A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We need $D^2\equiv D\pmod{10}$ hence $D(D-1)$ must be a multiple of $10$. This implies that $D\in\{0,1,5,6\}$.

Next, the tens digit of $(CD)^2=(10\cdot C+D)^2=100\cdot C^2+20\cdot C\cdot D+D^2$ is determined by the ones digit of $2\cdot C\cdot D$ and the tens digit of $D^2$.

- For $D=0$ we need $2\cdot 0\cdot C\equiv C\pmod {10}$, so $C=0$.
- For $D=1$ we need $2\cdot 1\cdot C\equiv C\pmod {10}$, so $C=0$.
- For $D=5$ we need $2\cdot 5\cdot C+2\equiv C\pmod {10}$, so $C=2$
- For $D=6$ we need $2\cdot 6\cdot C+3\equiv C\pmod {10}$, so $C=7$

Thus the full list of answers is
$$00^2=0000\quad 01^2=0001\quad 25^2=0625\quad 76^2=5776 $$
and possibly you won't count the first three as valid.

Comment: It is not a coincidence that $00+01=1$ and $25+76=101$ which is an interesting fact to explore. It is possible to show that these four can be extended in such a way that the square of the $n$ digit extension ends in the same $n$ digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow leading zeros, there are three more. $D$ must be $0,1,5,6$.  You can then just try them all-there are only $40$ possibilities.  As $0,1$ don't carry, in both cases we must have $C=0$.  For $5$ it has to be $2$, giving $00,01,25,76$

Answer (score 0):

$ABCD=(CD)^2$ can be translated as $100n + x = x^2$ which implies 
$x^2 - x \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$.

$$ \text{$x^2-x \equiv 0 \pmod{100} \iff x(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ 
    and $x(x-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{25}$}$$

$$x^2-x \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \iff x \in \{\bar 0_{4}, \bar1_{4} \}$$

$$x^2-x \equiv 0 \pmod{25} \iff x \in \{\bar 0_{25}, \bar1_{25} \}$$

$$x\equiv a \pmod{4} \ \wedge \ x \equiv b \pmod{25} \iff x \equiv 25a - 24b \pmod{100}$$

\begin{align}
   x \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \ \wedge \ x \equiv 0 \pmod{25} \iff x \equiv 0 \pmod{100} \\
   x \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \ \wedge \ x \equiv 1 \pmod{25} \iff x \equiv 76 \pmod{100} \\
   x \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \ \wedge \ x \equiv 0 \pmod{25} \iff x \equiv 25 \pmod{100} \\
   x \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \ \wedge \ x \equiv 1 \pmod{25} \iff x \equiv 1 \pmod{100} \\
\end{align}

So, we get

- 00^2 = 0000
- 01^2 = 0001
- 25^2 = 0625
- 76^2 = 5776

Answer (score -1):

If a programmatic solution (Python 2.7) is acceptable, then:

```
for n in range(0,100):
    if (n*n)%100 == n:
        print "%04d"%(n*n)
```

Gives:

```
0000
0001
0625
5776
```